# Will blockchain.info change my BTC adress each time after i SEND my BTC?

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees, blockchain.info

I would like to know a way to send BTC from 1 wallet but different adress each time. (because of transaction fees i dont want to use few different wallets for this)

Blockchain.info changes your BTC adress after you recieve transaction. Will it do the same after you send a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that a new bitcoin address is used for every transaction, this is best for your privacy. So each time you receive a transaction, you should use a new address. Each time you send a transaction, your wallet should generate a brand new change address for you.

I think you are confusing the terms ‘address’ and ‘wallet’. An address is the string of random-looking characters that you can send bitcoin to, it will usually look something like this: 19STQThjmUqf2veMCWNb7JhErguiCBdy3r.

A wallet is a collection of addresses, controlled by some software that allows to to send/receive transactions.

I’m general, each time you publish a transaction you will need to include a transaction fee if you want it confirmed in the blockchain. I recommend doing some research into how transaction fees work and are calculated so you can learn how to transact most efficiently.

Comment: Thank you. Will blockchain.info wallet change "adress" from which i'm sending bitcoin every time i send it?

For example: 
If i send 0.1 Bitcoin from my blockchain.info wallet, it will be send from AAA adress
.If after that i send another 0.1 Bitcoin from the same wallet, will it be sent from BBB adress? Or it will be sent from the same AAA adress?

Comment: If blockchain.info follows best practices, it will send from address ‘bbb’. As a user this shouldn’t be a worry, the wallet software will automatically manage this for you.

Comment: To go a little deeper: when ‘address aaa’ is spent, ALL of the balance is spent. This is how bitcoin works, you cannot only spend half of an address’ balance. If an address contains more btc than you’d like to spend, then a ‘change address’ is created for you in your wallet, and the excess is sent there (so you still control it, but it is in a new address). It is possible to use a pre-existing address as the change address (eg spend from address aaa, send change to address aaa), but as I mentioned this is bad for user privacy).